# Should oauth creds ever be stored in a database?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, oauth, access-token

I am connecting with a 3rd party via oauth2, on behalf of an organisation. That means 1 user will login to the third party service via the oauth flow, and then every other user should be able to access the third party's data.

What are the security implications of storing the access token in my database? Are there any best practices for doing this, or is it a terrible idea?

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the system you are working with access tokens should expire after about an hour so there is really no reason to store them anywhere.

If the system returns a refresh token that can be used to request a new access token when the user is not online.  Storing the refresh token is a good idea if you need to access their data when they are not around to authorize you.